# Is it possible to write the function $f(x) = i \textrm{erf} (ix)$ (with $i$ imaginary unit) in a way that doesn't involve complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis

Studying a physical problem I crashed into this differential equation (condition: $\lim_{x \to 0} = 0$)
\begin{equation*}
y' + A x y + B x^4 = 0 
\end{equation*}
where $x,A,B \in \mathbb{R}^+$. With the help of a good book and of a good software I founded
\begin{equation*}
y(x) = \frac{3B}{A^2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2A}} e^{-\frac{Ax^2}{2}} 
\textrm{erf} \left( i x \sqrt{\frac{A}{2}} \right) i - \frac{B}{A} x^3 + \frac{3B}{A^2} x
\end{equation*}
I checked that this is really the solution I was looking for, but I have a problem: I want to use this function into a spreadsheet, whose erf doesn't accept imaginary number. So I wonder if it is possible to write my $y(x)$ in a way that doesn't involve imaginary number. The problem is clearly in the odd function $ f(x) = i \textrm{erf} (ix)$  (despite the appearance, a $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ function). I sketch this function here near the origin (I'm interested to the right side $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$). Thanks a lot!
[image]

Comment: You might want to check the introduction of [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Answer (score 1):

The **imaginary error function** ${\rm erfi}(z)$ is defined by

$${\rm erfi}(z)=-i{\rm erf}(iz)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{iz}e^{-t^2}d(-it)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^z e^{u^2}du. $$

This follows from the substitution $u=-it$ (and complex analysis allows us to handle nonreal bounds on the integral; it becomes a path integral in the complex plane).

Comment: Thank you but I can't insert an integral into a spreadsheet cell. Of course using spreadsheet I could solve numerically my ODE but I'd like to have a formula because I have to use this result to solve numerically another problem, and I need this formula in every of thousands steps I do (if I don't have a formula, numerical work became too much, errors propagate, computer crash, I became crazy :-)).

Comment: OP: All this background SHOULD HAVE BEEN MENTIONED in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I said that I need to write my function into a spreadsheet cell, I thought this was sufficient and that there were no reason to run the risk to bore readers with excessive details.

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro If you want a formula without an integral, clearly you're out of luck. This is a special function, not an elementary function. You'll need to find a different way to obtain the values in the spreadsheet. Why aren't you using a CAS or something more suited to this kind of work? (By the way, I remember I used to be able to compute integrals in MS Excel by using cells for Riemann sums, but it's surely inefficient..) There's a good chance if you ask about your *original* numerical problem, we will be able to help with that.

Comment: The original problem is that I want to write the solution of my ODE in a way that is readable by a spreadsheet. With the help of a software I searched the McLaurin series founding this delightful identity
$$
i \textrm{erf} (i x) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{x}^{2n-1}}{n!-\frac{\left( n-1\right) !}{2}}}
$$
(I checked it works until Taylor depth 100, that is first 50 sum terms). Anyway, unless you recognize in this sum an elementary function that I could use in a spreadsheet cell, this beautiful formula doesn't solve my problem. Maybe I'll try to work using many Taylor terms

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro The imaginary error function is **not** an elementary function. Perhaps use numerical methods to integrate, or runge-kutta to numerically solve the ODE. Or even use a CAS to fill out the spreadsheet.

Comment: @whacka I agree, spreadsheet (in many situations a very powerful tool, in my opinion maybe underestimate) are not the best when there are analytic fineness like the one of my question. Anyway I solved my problem observing that for $x \ll \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$ (luckily not so much restrictive in my physical problem) the solution can be written $y(x) \approx -\frac{b {x}^{5}}{5}$. This should work.